# Is there any document(doc,docx) editor available in javascript?

Tags: editor, document

Can any one suggest me any library in javascript(client end) document editor where user can view and edit the documents like doc, docx, odf etc.

I have tried [webodf](http://webodf.org/) but it doesn't support doc/docx. Also, it's not getting implemented properly as editor.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to look for converters, and then edit the converted content.

I've been looking for a working solution now for a couple of weeks, and the best I've found to date is [docx2html](https://github.com/lalalic/docx2html).

Depending on your development platform you might also want to Google 'ONLYOFFICE Document Server Community Edition'. They have in page [editors](https://www.onlyoffice.com/features.aspx#editors) for Word, Excel and Powerpoint - but they're asp. It's an open source platform and available on Github. Might be worth a look though.

Comment: Thanks. I will check it out.

Comment: For the ones still looking at the solution, here is a good library that does that https://github.com/mwilliamson/mammoth.js